# Regular Expression (PHP) => greater that or if not

Tags: php, regex

It is possible to have in a regular expression (php), something like '>' or 'if not' ¿?

For example: I have a 5 number string 'XXXXX': '00054', '47690', '20593'...

I need a regular expression that verify:

1. 5 numbers
2. Greater that 1

I had this: '/^[0-9]{5}$/' but doesn't verify the greater than '00001' !

I'm looking for something like '>' or 'if not 00000'...

Thanks

PS: I know that can be done with: if((int)$string > 1)

Comment: `/^(?!00000)[0-9]{5}$/`

Comment: or add the `1` in a character class for greater than 1, `^(?!0{4}[01])\d{5}$`.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? PHP will auto-juggle types for you, so `'47564' > 47563` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can figure out 2 ways:

```
/^(?!00000)\d{5}$/
```

This first checks that the start is not followed by 5 zeros, then searches for 5 digits.

```
/^(?:[1-9]\d{4}|\d[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{3}[1-9]\d|\d{4}[1-9])$/
```

This one checks for 5 combinations, each of which contains a non-zero digit in one of the 5 positions.

Answer (score 3):

When I am stuck with a regex - the first question I always ask myself is "Is what I am describing a regular language?" - And the easiest way to answer this question is to try and draw a finite state machine - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine. In your case, it is possible and it will give you one answer of how to write the regular expression. A simple finite state machine for this problem would start with asking - is the first character a 0 or 1-9? If its 0 go down one path (do a similar check on the next digit), if its 1-9 go down another (check if there are 4 more numbers afterwards). [image: half done finite state]

Seeing how the rest of the picture will play out we can create a regex that looks like this:

```
[1-9][0-9]{4} | 0[1-9][0-9]{3} | 00[1-9][0-9]{2} | 000[1-9][0-9] | 0000[1-9]
```

P.S. The image above is incomplete and is there just to show an illustration of how to start the finite state machine - I drew it quickly so it doesn't have the double circles to show "final" states and the tree does not go all the way down to 5 digits. If you are interested, I can finish the rest of the tree, but thought it would be overkill in this situation.

**EDIT** By demand for a centipede-duck - here is a more complete drawing
[image: larger finite state machine]

Comment: Is this what happens when a centipede and a duck use the machine from The Fly?

Comment: @rjdown Great question! I believe you are correct but you need to add in the drawing abilities of a 5 year old to really grasp the concept.

Comment: I decided to finish off my centipede-duck drawing for completeness. It now has pretty colors.

Comment: I can see this being a blockbuster